# Show a href link on a different hidden div when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, elementor

I haven't seen this proble manywhere, no clue if it could be possible but is there a possibility for me to have a link to a website but when I press the link the website opens up in a div on my site?

The reason for why I want this is becuase I have articles on my site and instead of opening the article itself I want it to be when I click the article it should open in a div that is hidden normally but shows when an article is clicked with the full article on it

```
`document.querySelectorAll('.title').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    var get_href = document.querySelectorAll('.title').getAttribute('href')
    event.preventDefault()
    alert('get_href')
  })
})
```

Comment: Want to display only the post or page from the other site on your site? Please provide more information on what you already have as a code.

Comment: What you want is definitely JavaScript, and probably AJAX.

Comment: you can use iframe?

Comment: allot of things are possible, but it really depends on what you exactly want, You could scrape the website to get the right data or show the page in an iframe. But also the source where you get it from must allow it, many don't allow it to scrape there data/content from there website in any kind

Comment: My post is edited with code for you guys can se what I got so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this using AJAX and JavaScript.

First,

- detect a click on a link, (`addEventListener`)
- then cancel the event so the user won't be redirected to the link, (`event.preventDefault()`)
- grab the link and (`getAttribute('href')`)
- load it onto your page.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do with that, but I think the most easiest way would be to create an iFrame and set the link as URL, because otherwise you might get problems with CORS (if the page is on a different URL and you don't own the other page).

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   if(event.target.matches('a[href]')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var url = event.target.getAttribute('href');
      // Do whatever you want, create/open a div, ...
   }
});
```

Here is an example of loading the website into an iframe: https://jsfiddle.net/1hefuLrs/

Comment: exactly, I edited my post so yo ucan see what I got so far but what you gave me is what I am trying to do. I have posts on my page and I dont want it to open in a new page, I want it to open on the same page in a hidden div or w/e so I later on can animate it to sldie into the screen and show the full post